# Insert a file into PostgreSQL BYTEA field using PHP

Tags: postgresql, php, insert, bytea

The previous answers have been horribly complex for the scope of this project.
I want to take the `$_POST` result as a variable and insert it into a `BYTEA` field of a table.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$file = $_POST["file"];
```

file is the file itself submitted from the form on the previous page

```
pg_prepare($conn, "register_user_info", 'INSERT INTO fileDB.assignment(pawprint, name, number, section, file) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)'); 
pg_execute($conn, "register_user_info", array($username, "1", "1", "1", $file));
```

I need to insert the file itself into the file column of my database. How can I make this happen?

Comment: You're using PHP with PostgreSQL - you're not using `psql`, the command-line client for PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be an SO question, but it is to late to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

- Use PDO, which properly supports binary parameters; or
- Use `pg_escape_bytea` with string substitution into the query text.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17121791/398670 .